# iOS7 - jquery.touchSwipe interfere with on click and webkit-touch-callout

Tags: jquery, html, css, ios7

I'm building a web app but with iOS7 there's an interference between [jquery.touchSwipe](http://labs.rampinteractive.co.uk/touchSwipe/demos/) and my "on click" events.

The web app works great on older iOS versions, no obstruction there.

The thing is if I include the jquery.touchSwipe plugin to my web app, the "on clicks" events are not working; the "-webkit-touch-callout: none;" will neither work meaning that my divs become selectable (not what I want). The swipe function from jquery.touchSwipe will work though.

If I get rid of the jquery.touchSwipe plugin then all my "on clicks" work fine

Here's what I have as an html (btn_bottom div as an exemple, which is a button placed at the bottom of my app):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
  <title>Jh Portfolio | mobile</title>

  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="57x57" href="jh_logo57.png" />
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="72x72" href="jh_logo72.png" />
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="114x114" href="jh_logo114.png" />
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="157x157" href="jh_logo157.png" />
  <!-- stylesheets -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="layout.css" type="text/css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="info/layout_info.css" type="text/css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="clients/layout_clients.css" type="text/css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="each_clients_bazar.css" type="text/css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="contact/layout_contact.css" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>

  <div id="...">
     <div id="..." class="...">
        <div id="..." class="..."></div>
        <div id="..."></div>
     </div>
  </div>
  <div id="..."></div>
  <div id="..."></div>
  <div id="..."></div>
  <div id="..."></div>
  <div id="..."></div>
  <div id="..."></div>

  <div id="...">
     <div id="..." class="...">
        <img src="---.gif" width="..." height="..." alt="...">
     </div>
  </div>
  <div id="...">
     <div id="..." class="..."></div>
  </div>
  <div id="...">
     <div id="..." class="...">
        <div id="...">
           <div id="..."></div>
           <div id="..."></div>
           <div id="..."></div>
           <div id="..."></div>
           <div id="...">
              <div id="..." class="..."></div>
              <div id="..." class="..."></div>
              <div id="..." class="..."></div>
              <div id="..." class="..."></div>
           </div>
        </div>
     </div>
  </div>

  <div id="...">
     <div id="..." class="...">
        <div id="...">
           <div id="..."></div>
           <div id="..."></div>
           <div id="..."></div>
           <div id="..."></div>
           <div id="...">
              <div id="..." class="..."></div>
              <div id="..." class="..."></div>
              <div id="..." class="..."></div>
              <div id="..." class="..."></div>
           </div>
        </div>
     </div>
  </div>

  <div id="...">
     <div id="..." class="...">
        <div id="..."></div>
        <div id="..."></div>
        <div id="..." class="..."></div>
        <div id="..." class="..."></div>
     </div>
  </div>

  <div id="...">
     <div id="...">
        <div id="..."></div>
        <div id="..."></div>
     </div>
  </div>

  <div id="btn_bottom"></div>
  <div id="..."></div>
  <div id="..."></div>
  <div id="..."></div>
  <div id="..."></div>

<script src="preloader.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="jquery.viewport.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="iscroll.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.touchSwipe.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="jhmobile.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<!-- This is for a canvas animation-->
<script src="http://code.createjs.com/easeljs-0.6.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.createjs.com/tweenjs-0.4.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.createjs.com/movieclip-0.6.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.createjs.com/preloadjs-0.3.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="clients/esb/esb_728x90.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the css of that button ("div id="btn_bottom"):

```
#btn_bottom {
   margin: auto;
   position: relative;
   margin-top: -191px;
   height: 191px;
   width: 229px;
   clear:both;
   opacity:1;
   z-index:101;
   -webkit-touch-callout: none;
   -ms-touch-action: none;
   cursor: pointer;
}
```

Facts:

- My .html was successfully checked as HTML5 by W3C.
- I use the latest Jquery as well as jquery.touchSwipe.
- jquery.touchSwipe swiping works great.
- Everything works great ("swipe" & "buttons") on all desktop browsers as well as older iOS.

I would like to know if anyone has any idea why the buttons are not clickable if I combine the touchSwipe plugin with the other scripts (under iOS7).

Thanks guys.

Answer (score 1):

If anyone face the same problem I just wanted to say that the best solution I found was to switch to the [touchWipe](http://www.example.com/) plugin instead of touchswipe.

The only inconvenient with touchWipe is that it won't work on desktop browsers but since I intended to use this effect for mobile it's perfect.